# Linux Common Clock Framework - Prevent clock from being disabled

Tags: clock, device-tree

I want to output a 600kHz clock for syncing a switching regulator with my i.MX6UL from NXP. I specified a clock in my devicetree:

```
sync0: sync0 {
    #clock-cells = <0>;
    compatible = "pwm-clock";
    clock-output-names = "pwm_sync";
    pwms = <&pwm3 0 1667>;
    status = "okay";
};
```

I don't have any consumer in defined in my devicetree, because it's nothing software specific, so the common clock framework switches off my clock every time. I can overrule this with clk_ignore_unused, but this would prevent all clocks from being disabled. Is there a way, to force enable only a single clock?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register this clk separately to the linux kernel framework with this `CLK_IGNORE_UNUSED` flag:

```
struct clk_init_data {
    const char      *name;
    const struct clk_ops    *ops;
    const char      * const *parent_names;
    u8          num_parents;
    unsigned long       flags;   // Here you have to pass CLK_IGNORE_UNUSED flag.
};
```

Comment: But there's no way, to specify this in the device tree for this single clock I assume?

Comment: This is kernel flag. Why you want to keep in dts? you have multiple platforms? (or) or you can pass clk_unused flag in uboot params.

Comment: There's only one clock I want to stay on, that's way I thought about the device-tree node

Comment: no need of dts entry if it is only one. dts is required for more than one platform.